# How to mock argparse with pytest in bigger Python cli application

Tags: python, pytest, argparse, python-poetry

I'm working on the following application: https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties

I didn't include unit-tests from the beginning which is bad, I know but I wanted to concentrate on the functionality. Anyway, I want to add unit-tests now but I have big issues in doing so.

I already adapted a lot of stuff which can be found on this [feature branch](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/tree/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit). Since I'm working with `poetry` I invoke pytest using `poetry run pytest --cov=duties tests/`. I could run a basic unit test (`tests/protocol/test_connection.py`). However, the second test I tried (`tests/protocol/test_ethereum.py`) failed and revealed a much bigger issue with regards to argparse. I try to describe the issue as detailed as I can:

1. In my test file I want to test [this function](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/blob/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit/duties/protocol/ethereum.py#L41)
2. In the testfile you can see that I want to mock the function [send_beacon_api_request](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/blob/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit/tests/protocol/test_ethereum.py#L18)
3. However, this function is imported from module `duties.protocol.request` and within this module I also import the [BeaconNode class](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/blob/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit/duties/protocol/request.py#L15) which is then used within `send_beacon_api_request` or in one of the called private functions respectively. The issue is that the `BeaconNode class` [imports my parsed arguments](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/blob/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit/duties/protocol/connection.py#L10)
4. Now when I run the test I get the following error from pytest:

```
tests/protocol/test_ethereum.py:5: in <module>
    from duties.protocol.ethereum import get_current_slot
duties/protocol/ethereum.py:12: in <module>
    from duties.protocol.request import CalldataType, send_beacon_api_request
duties/protocol/request.py:18: in <module>
    beacon_node = BeaconNode()
duties/protocol/connection.py:19: in __init__
    self.__arguments = get_arguments()
duties/cli/arguments.py:305: in get_arguments
    arguments = __get_raw_arguments()
duties/cli/arguments.py:192: in __get_raw_arguments
    return parser.parse_args()
/home/towo/miniconda3/envs/poetry-py312/lib/python3.12/argparse.py:1894: in parse_args
    self.error(msg % ' '.join(argv))
/home/towo/miniconda3/envs/poetry-py312/lib/python3.12/argparse.py:2655: in error
    self.exit(2, _('%(prog)s: error: %(message)s\n') % args)
/home/towo/miniconda3/envs/poetry-py312/lib/python3.12/argparse.py:2642: in exit
    _sys.exit(status)
E   SystemExit: 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
usage: eth-duties [...options]
eth-duties: error: unrecognized arguments: --cov=duties tests/
```

It looks like that I also need to mock argparse which I already [tried](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/blob/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit/tests/protocol/test_ethereum.py#L11). I know that I need to mock the get_arguments function based on the module I want to test. Same thing is working [here](https://github.com/TobiWo/eth-duties/blob/feature/add-unit-tests-intermediate-commit/tests/protocol/test_connection.py#L9). But this doesn't work and I get the above error. I might have a misunderstanding of pytest here so maybe someone can help.

I know it is hard to grasp because the application is pretty big already.

Since these kind of imports happening often times I'm pretty sure I will have this issue multiple times.

Comment: Arguably, you should go through your code and make sure `parse_args` never gets called without an explicit argument. Your script's main entry point can ensure that `None` gets passed explicitly, which ensures `sys.argv` is parsed. Any tests can make sure a real list, rather than `None`, is passed.

Comment: Do you recognize the `usage`, and/or the unrecognized `--cov=duties tests`?   I'm not familiar with `poetry`, but testing `argparse` (or any commandline parser) is tricky.  The test framework may have its own commandline arguments and parser.  Resolving conflicting requirements of multiple parsers is tricky.  Unit testing with argparse has come up in a lot of SO, though not many with `poetry` as well.

Comment: @chepner I read about that as well so maybe I will give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @hpaulj The `--cov` option is to create an overview about code/test coverage. I can try without but this isn't a good solution. Also the test `tests/protocol/test_connection.py` work with the same command line call.